# When studying 2D gabor functions why is a gaussian called elliptical?

Tags: statistics, soft-question, fourier-analysis, normal-distribution, signal-processing

Consider $$G(x,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma\beta}e^{-\pi\left[\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{\sigma^2}+\frac{(y-y_0)^2}{\beta^2}\right]}e^{i[\xi_0x+\nu_0y]}.$$ This is the product of a complex plane wave and what this paper calls an elliptical Gaussian. I see the complex plane wave but why is $$e^{-\pi\left[\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{\sigma^2}+\frac{(y-y_0)^2}{\beta^2}\right]}$$ called "elliptical" and not just a Gaussian? Are all Gaussians elliptical?

Comment: the exponent has the form of the fundamental equation of an ellipse

Comment: The level sets of that exponential piece are ellipses (and are not circles, if $\sigma \neq \beta$). That's all. All multivariate Gaussians have this property, with the caveat that it is possible for the level sets to be *degenerate* ellipsoids, if the covariance matrix is singular. Degenerate ellipsoids, after change of coordinates, are essentially like cylinders.